# How to position a GreasePencil Stroke via scripting?

Tags: python, scripting

I am trying to automate blinking animation via scripting. I can move grease pencil objects, but I need to move a stroke inside a layer (I am using masking, so I can't convert the strokes into individual objects). I couldn't find a way to position a stroke in the GPencilStroke docs. Is there a way to transform strokes with bpy?